# How to print image on MTPII bluetooth printer without restarting the it

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, outputstream

I am printing a capured receipt as an image to bluetooth printer using the function in the code below.

the function is using resize image to compare the image width and the paper width. It is printing but the only problem is that i have to first power the printer off for the next printout to be aligned well on the margin.

When i don't power it off, the printer is starting from the middle of the paper.
I tried to printing a receipt in form of text but it don't know how to format it in tabular layout. 
I want any advise on how to fix this. thanks

```
boolean printImage(CallbackContext callbackContext, String msg) throws IOException {
        try {

            final String encodedString = msg;
            final String pureBase64Encoded = encodedString.substring(encodedString.indexOf(",") + 1);

            final byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(pureBase64Encoded.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
//          Log.e("BASE64", Arrays.toString(decodedBytes));
            Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);

            bitmap = decodedBitmap;
            int mWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            int mHeight = bitmap.getHeight();


            bitmap = resizeImage(bitmap, 48* 8, mHeight);


            byte[] bt = decodeBitmap(bitmap);
               bitmap.recycle();
               mmOutputStream.write(bt);

            // tell the user data were sent
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data Sent");
            callbackContext.success("Data Sent");

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errMsg =(e.getMessage()==null)?"Null Error":e.getMessage();
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", errMsg);
            e.printStackTrace();
            callbackContext.error(errMsg);
        }
        return false;
    }
```